# System.OutOfMemoryException was thrown when loading all datatable at once

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, dataset, out-of-memory

I'm working with database that has almost 8 millions records in one table. I know it's huge data and should not be loaded all of them at once. But, it's important for my project to load all these records to dataset which resides in memory.

When I'm trying to fill datatable in dataset using the below code:

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();
            foreach (Component component in EnumerateComponents())
            {
                string name = component.GetType().Name;
                if (name.Contains("baghadadpTableAdapter"))
                {
                    string TableName = name.Substring(0, name.IndexOf("TableAdapter"));
                   baghadadpTableAdapter1.Fill(ds1.persons);
                }
            }
            stopwatch.Stop();
            TimeSpan time = stopwatch.Elapsed;
```

The following error occurs in line "baghadadpTableAdapter1.Fill(ds1.persons);":

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: 'Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.'
```

How to solve this issue and the same time load all these huge data to the datatable persons in ds1

Comment: is there a reason that you want all of this in Memory? Can't you use paging?

Comment: "But, it's important for my project to load all these records to dataset which resides in memory." can you explain why?

Comment: The reason behind storing those data in memory because the user wants to load these data from the server, then disconnect from the server, and navigate it offline. In first meeting, I explained to him this issue could happened, but he insisted to find the way to achieve this, so I told him I will do my best to figure this out, and that why I asked you guys to help with this.

Answer (score 3):

You could:

- increase the memory on the machine,
- load only the relevant columns.

Ultimately though, you will need to think of how to process the records in chunks. I don't know how you application works, but I haven't met a scenario when the application needs to have super fast access to 8 million objects.

Comment: @tymtam so you say that if I load a specific fields could low the load on memory and may be the data cloud be uploaded all of them at once, is that what you say?

Answer (score 1):

`DataTable` is notoriously bad for large sets. I have seen tables that use 6-7 *times* as much memory as the raw data.

If you *really* need to store that much data in memory, then consider changing to a `List` of domain objects rather than a `DataTable`. But I also challenge the "need" to store millions or records in memory.

Comment: Can you please explain to me what you mean about List of domains?

Comment: A list of _domain objects_. For example, instead of filling an `Employee` data table, create a `List<Employee>` and fill it with `Employee` objects from that data.

Answer (score 0):

I would just page the data set. There are several different ways to do this that you can research.

Comment: The reason behind storing those data in memory because the user wants to load these data from the server, then disconnect from the server, and navigate it offline. In first meeting, I explained to him this issue could happened, but he insisted to find the way to achieve this, so I told him I will do my best to figure this out, and that why I asked you guys to help with this.

Comment: You will.need to make sure the machine you are loading into has enough RAM then. You might try some scheme of copying the data to hard disk and paging from that instead.

Comment: Good idea, I will try to load the data and save them on local database or file and then navigate them. I will post an answer as soon as this idea worked for me.